# Display Column Data as a Row in ASP.NET Core View

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, asp.net-core-mvc

I have Class name `Fuel` with have following data:
This is my **Model** Class:

```
public class Fuel
    {
        public int FuelID { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public DateTime OrderDate { get; set; }
        public double Qty { get; set; }
    }
```

Data in Table.

```
Name   | OrderDate | Qty
H&S1   | 1/1/2008  | 100
H&S1   | 1/2/2008  | 200
H&S1   | 2/2/2008  | 350
H&S2   | 2/28/2008 | 220
H&S2   | 3/12/2008 | 250
H&S2   | 3/15/2008 | 2150
```

And the **IActionResult** is like below:

```
public IActionResult GetRes()
        {
            List<Fuel> myList = List<Fuel>();

            var query = myList
                .GroupBy(c => c.Name)
                .Select(g => new {
                    Name= g.Key,
                    Jan = g.Where(c => c.OrderDate.Month == 1).Sum(c => c.Qty),
                    Feb = g.Where(c => c.OrderDate.Month == 2).Sum(c => c.Qty),
                    March = g.Where(c => c.OrderDate.Month == 3).Sum(c => c.Qty)
                });
            return View(myList);
        }
```

here is my **View**

```
@model IEnumerable<CoreServices.Model.Fuel>

@{ 
    Layout = null;
}
<div class="row">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>Name</td>
            <td>Date</td>
            <td>Quantity</td>
        </tr>
        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>@item.Name</td>
                <td>@item.Date</td>
                <td>@item.Qty</td>
            </tr>
        }
    </table>
</div>
```

But the Result Show like

```
    Name   | OrderDate | Qty
    H&S1   | 1/1/2008  | 100
    H&S1   | 1/2/2008  | 200
    H&S1   | 2/2/2008  | 350
    H&S2   | 2/28/2008 | 220
    H&S2   | 3/12/2008 | 250
    H&S2   | 3/15/2008 | 2150
```

And I want to show the result on **View** like this:

```
Name| Jan- 2008 | Feb- 2008 | Mar - 2008| Total
H&S1| 100       | 350       |  250      | 700
H&S2| 200       | 220       | 2150      | 2570
```

Can anyone guide me how to do display above format on View?

Comment: what have you tried so far - hint: look at a for-loop in your cshtml

Comment: could u plz add your `.cshtml` file to your question?

Comment: Two tables you are showing are the same.

Comment: @ershoaib  Plx check now

Comment: @JohnB check it

Comment: @Llazar not i want show column data as a row in .cshtml view

Comment: OP wants to transform / group by...

Comment: ideas: design that model so that it caters for the needs of the view, then worry about how you are going to hydrate the model with data next.